# using regex and php

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to figure out how to convert string below string to multiple lines where it will add comma after two consecutive letters. Anyhelp is appreciated.

```
$myLine = "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD";
$myLine= preg_replace('/((?<=\[a-zA-Z]\b))/', ',', $myLine);
```

output would be

```
1234:21:3AB,
3459435:2343RT,
23432523:CD,
```

THanks,
jp

I like all the answers, i appreciate everyone pitching in to help and ran through all the various different ways of getting this to work. it is amazing what regexp php can do one thing so many different ways. thanks to all again!!!!

Comment: Do you mean 2 consecutive letters or two /same/ letters (like AA,ABB)

Comment: to consecutive letters like in the above string there are AB RT CD etc... end result would be 1234:21:3AB,3459435:2343RT,23432523:CD, new line would be after comma (sorry about that)

Comment: It's missing some details. What's with the "multiple lines"? Can you edit and post the expected output, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: end result would be 1234:21:3AB,3459435:2343RT,23432523:CD,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I came up with quickly.

```
$myLine = "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD";
$myLine= preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{2})/', "$1,\n", $myLine);
```

Outputs:

```
1234:21:3AB,
3459435:2343RT,
23432523:CD,
```

Or, if you don't want the trailing comma:

```
$myLine = "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD";
$myLine= preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{2}(?!$))/', "$1,\n", $myLine);
```

Outputs:

```
1234:21:3AB,
3459435:2343RT,
23432523:CD
```

Comment: can fourth position from back to three in length be stripped at the same time or i will have to use another regexp so for example get 21:, 234, 523 ?

Comment: @jpp: I would do that in a separate regex.  Or better yet, you could `substr` to get the range of characters you want.

Comment: but substr from back of the string is possible?

Comment: @jpp: Yup.  Have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/substr).  You can use negative numbers to start from (and omit from) the end of the string.  So, to get the characters you want you'd do `substr($str, -7, 3)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myLine = "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD";
$myLine = preg_replace('/([a-z]{2})/i', '$1,', $myLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you want the new-lines, but as far as the consecutive letters go, it would be something like:

```
$myLine= preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{2})/', '$1,', $myLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
preg_replace('~([a-z]{2})~i', "$1,", $myLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$myLine = "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD";
$myLine= preg_replace("/([a-z]{2})/i","$1,\n", $myLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `{2}` to make it match exactly twice.

```
/((?<=[a-zA-Z]{2}))/
```

Also, you can use `\w` for any word character.

```
/((?<=\w{2}\b))/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble interpreting your question. Assuming you mean you'd like your sample data of "1234:21:3AB3459435:2343RT23432523:CD" to be converted to "1234:21:3AB,3459435:2343RT,23432523:CD":

```
$myLine= preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{2})/','$1,',$myLine);
```

should work. The pattern matches exactly two letter characters in a row, and the parentheses around it make that match accessible as a reference in the replacement. The replacement then takes the two matched characters and just puts a comma after them. See http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for more details.

If you want the result to be multiple lines (e.g. for prettier output) just change the replacement expression to include a new line, e.g.

```
$myLine= preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{2})/','$1'.",\n",$myLine);
```